# How To Grab Image Source From CSS Background Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my first question ever, please show some love!

I'm trying to grab the background image from a div element and append it to a div every time I push a bottom. Below is the mockup code:

```
<div class="img"></div>

.img {
background: url("local image file");
}

function addImage(imageSrc) {
  var imageSrc = document.getElementByClassName('img')[0].getComputedStyle.background
}
```

I could not find a way to grab the local path inside the background url(""). Can someone please help? I only know vanilla Javascript.

Thank you!

Comment: One tip: it's `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName` (plural)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('img')[0]).getPropertyValue('background')
```

Comment: Ur sir is almost current, I added .slice(4 , -1) at the end to slice out the url and brackets like the above answer and it worked!!! Thank you, my savior! I truly cannot thank you enough seriously! I've been looking for this answer for two nights. Respect!

Answer (score 3):

Using the `getComputedStyle` on the window.

```
const img = document.getElementsByClassName('img')[0];
const url = getComputedStyle(img).backgroundImage.slice(5, -2);
```

I get the URL from `getComputedStyle(element).backgroundImage` then slice out the url and brackets surrounding the link

Comment: Saves quotes, as well. `.slice(5, -2)` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I used .slice(4, -1) in conjunction with the answer below and it worked! I've been looking for the answer for two nights now!!! Ur sirs are truly my faith in humanity! Respect!

Answer (score 1):

`getComputedStyle` is a property of `window`. Since `window` is always implicit, it can be omitted. Here's your solution:

```js
const imgSrc = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.img')).backgroundImage.slice(5, -2);
console.log(imgSrc);
```

```css
.img{
  background:url('test.png');
}
```

```html
<div class='img'></div>
```